# Fill array in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill a new array within a loop, but I can't figure it out.

What I need is, that I filter all value's from my temporary array to set to my new array.
all value's that start with "+" need to get into the array "my_hash_plus". 
this is what I have now.

```
var my_hash_plus = new Array;   
$.each(my_hash_plus_tmp, function(_, temp) {
    if (tmp[0] == "+") {
        my_hash_plus[] = temp;
    }
});
```

I noticed that I can't fill my array with `[]` in js, but if I those things then `my_hash_plus` becomes a normal var... So my question is: what is the best way to get all the value's from the array `my_hash_plus_tmp` that start with "+" into a new array (which I will call `my_hash_plus`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `push()`

```
var my_hash_plus = [];   

$.each(my_hash_plus_tmp, function(_, temp) {
    if (temp.charAt(0) == "+") {
        my_hash_plus.push( temp );
    }
});
```

In newer browser you can do it pretty easily without jQuery as well

```
var my_hash_plus = my_hash_plus_tmp.filter(function(it){return it.charAt(0)=='+'});
```

Comment: Well i understand the jQuery version. so i better use that one, hahaha.
thanks though :)